# Jquery is not working in salesforce

Tags: jquery, visualforce

Hii all,

I am trying to develop Range Slider in my VF page but it is not working.
    I am sharing my code with you.I am trying range slider which will show values on change when slider will move it will show values on that slider.

Thanks in advance!!

```
apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="false">

 script>
  $(function(){
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').text(ui.value);
        },
        create: function(event, ui) {
            var v=$(this).slider('value');
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').text(v);
        }
    });    
});
 /script>

 script>
 #demo { padding: 10px !important; }
 /script>

 div class="demo">
    div id="slider-vertical">``</div>
/div>

/apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

See Salesforce documentation on [Developing Apps with jQuery](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery)

You need to reference at least the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" />
```

You also need to use jQuery's no conflict mode and use `j$` in place of `$`

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Also the CSS looks like it should be inside a `'<style>'` tag and with `.demo` selector.

There is some weirdness with the code you've posted that it's missing all `<`